# Wordpress script with jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i hope you can help me with this, im testing a search box script for travel packages search but i think that is causing an conflict with WP Jquery, theme or a plugin, i included this code in the header which is used for the search box:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

(function(a){if(typeof define==='function'&&define.amd)    {define(['jquery'],a)}else{a(jQuery)}}(function($){if($.support.cors||!$.ajaxTransport||!window.XDomainRequest){return}var n=/^https?:\/\//i;var o=/^get|post$/i;var p=new RegExp('^'+location.protocol,'i');$.ajaxTransport('* text html xml json',function(j,k,l){if(!j.crossDomain||!j.async||!o.test(j.type)||!n.test(j.url)||!p.test(j.url)){return}var m=null;return{send:function(f,g){var h='';var i=(k.dataType||'').toLowerCase();m=new XDomainRequest();if(/^\d+$/.test(k.timeout)){m.timeout=k.timeout}m.ontimeout=function(){g(500,'timeout')};m.onload=function(){var a='Content-Length: '+m.responseText.length+'\r\nContent-Type: '+m.contentType;var b={code:200,message:'success'};var c={text:m.responseText};try{if(i==='html'||/text\/html/i.test(m.contentType)){c.html=m.responseText}else if(i==='json'||(i!=='text'&&/\/json/i.test(m.contentType))){try{c.json=$.parseJSON(m.responseText)}catch(e){b.code=500;b.message='parseerror'}}else if(i==='xml'||(i!=='text'&&/\/xml/i.test(m.contentType))){var d=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');d.async=false;try{d.loadXML(m.responseText)}catch(e){d=undefined}if(!d||!d.documentElement||d.getElementsByTagName('parsererror').length){b.code=500;b.message='parseerror';throw'Invalid XML: '+m.responseText;}c.xml=d}}catch(parseMessage){throw parseMessage;}finally{g(b.code,b.message,c,a)}};m.onprogress=function(){};m.onerror=function(){g(500,'error',{text:m.responseText})};if(k.data){h=($.type(k.data)==='string')?k.data:$.param(k.data)}m.open(j.type,j.url);m.send(h)},abort:function(){if(m){m.abort()}}}})}));

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://www.e-tsw.com/Search/Box?af=XX-XXX&ln=ESP&cu=PE",
    success: function (data) {
        jQuery("#liquidBoxContainer").html(data);
    }
});
```

And a div to display the box inside my wordpress post:

If i run this on a unique file, it works correctly displaying the search box, and displays a tooltip on search input boxes and datepick, but when i run it with wordpress, it displays the box, but the search and date fields dont work.

This is without wordpress, its fine :  [image]

This is with wordpress: [image]

on console i get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQkdo(...).timepicker is not a function

I hope you can help me, and also which one is the correct method to load this scripts and avoid this kind of errors?

Comment: This seems to be jquery version conflict problem, you need check which plugin need what version and resolve accordignly

Comment: In WordPress you should use wp_enqueue_script to include your JS file with dependancies. This will allow you to load jQuery via WordPress if it is not already loaded by another plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manual install of nivoslider on wordpress not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518228/manual-install-of-nivoslider-on-wordpress-not-working)

Comment: @vinayakj Thanks for the suggestions, which is the correct way to solve that kind of incompatibility problem with jquery versions?

Comment: Not sure if there is better way in wordpress.. but manually you can use jquery.noConflict() API.

Answer (score 0):

You should enqueue your jquery in your functions file like this:

```
// Load jQuery
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
       wp_deregister_script('jquery');
       wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"), false);
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery');    
    }
```